# MySql Insert Query Problem

Tags: php, mysql

Whats wrong with insert query.

```
$result = $conn->query("insert into user (fullname,username,email,passwd) values 
        ('".$data['fullname']."','".$data['username']."','".$data['email']."','".$data['fullname']."') " );
 if(!$result) {
    throw new Exception('Could not register you in database - please try again later.');
}
```

thanks

Comment: Looks ok to me. What error are you getting? Also, is your input safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly detail: you seem to pass fullname into passwd column - not sure if it is intentional.

Otherwise the code seems okay. Var_dump please whole string (with variable values filled in) you are passing into the query method and post it here.

And check the message returned by mysql via [mysql_error](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQhgIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.mysql-error.php&ei=gCpYTZP5M47qOabV1NkE&usg=AFQjCNF3oBpINP0JEZaSL1FKoHjqZevvBg&sig2=yUb1TCYUlTcEiDGFyfkcXA)/[mysqli::error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Also, good practice is to type SQL keywords in uppercase.

Comment: @ClosureCowboy He may have sanitized the $data array earlier, so I didn't bother reminding him.

Comment: thanks. the error message was. 'Errormessage: Duplicate entry 'asdf@gmail.com' for key 'user_email' Could not register you in database - please try again later.' Solved thanks again

Comment: @ClosureCowboy haramfull data is filter by this function. 'function filter_UserForm($data) { 
  $data = strip_tags(htmlentities(trim($data)));
  /* If the escape data not filter automatically, then we filter manually using addslashes */   
  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
   $data = addslashes($data);
  } 
  $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
  return $data;
 }'

Answer (score 0):

Check the message returned by MySQL via `mysql_error/mysqli::error` or add this to the end of your MySQL query to see the error on the browser.

```
die(mysql_error())
```

Secondly it looks like you are inputting in the wrong field or column

Answer (score -1):

Your query looks fine so it's almost certainty the content of the $data that is causing the error. We can't help you with the specific error unless you provide it.

One thing that comes to mind is that one of those values contains an apostrophe. In that case, you need to sanitize your data, which you should do anyway, in fact, because otherwise you are *extremely* vulnerable to people hacking your website.

Try using `addslashes($data['username'])` instead of just `$data['username']` in your query.

`addslashes()` adds slashes before characters like apostrophes.

Comment: Why is this -1? Not complaining, I'd just like to know what I'm saying wrong.